# Join two tables in codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, join

I'am trying to join two tables. Lets say `t1` and `t2`. `t1` has `fk t2_id`. but when I run the code nothing is shown in my view.

**Controller:**

```
 //..
 $data['city']= $this->state_model->name();
 $this->load->view('viewt', $data);
```

**Model:**

```
    function name(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('state');
    $this->db->join('city', 'city.state_id = state.id');
    $sql = $this->db->get();

    if ($sql->num_rows () >0) {
        foreach($sql->result() as $row) {
        $this->db->where('state_id','state.id');
        $r = $this->db->get('city');
        }

    return $r->result();

     }
     else {
     return null;   
            }
```

**View:**

```
 <?php foreach($city as $row):?>
  <?php echo $row->cityname; ?></br></br></br>
  <?php endforeach;?></br></br>
```

Thanks in advance

The Queries:

```
  SELECT `id`, `statename`
  FROM (`state`)
  ORDER BY `id` ASC

  SELECT *
FROM (`state`)
JOIN `city` ON `city`.`state_id` = `state`.`id`  

  SELECT *
  FROM (`city`)
  WHERE `state_id` = 'state.id'  

  SELECT *
  FROM (`city`)
  WHERE `state_id` = 'state.id'  

  SELECT *
  FROM (`city`)
  WHERE `state_id` = 'state.id'
```

Comment: Turn on profiling and let us see the raw queries:  $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);

Comment: @swatkins  queries are given above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $r variable will only have the last iteration thus the function will only return the last result set, so try this:

```
if ($sql->num_rows () >0) {
    foreach($sql->result() as $row) {
    $this->db->where('state_id',$row->state_id);
    $r[] = $this->db->get('city')->row();
    }

return $r;
```

Comment: i've tried with your code but give the error : Trying to get property of non-object. The line at which the error is showing is   <?php foreach($city as $row):?>

Comment: Then just change this: $r[] = $this->db->get('city')->result();  to this: $r[] = $this->db->get('city')->row();
See my edit... you have to either change that, or slightly modify your view since your data is now available via $row[0]->cityname. I suggest you edit the model.

Answer (score 0):

Check the latest query: `$this->db->last_query()`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you're getting three records back from your join - so we know that's working. But you're other 3 queries look incorrect. Try this:

```
if ($sql->num_rows () >0) {
    $r = array();
    foreach($sql->result() as $row) {

        // here, you need to replace 'state.id' with the actual
        // results from your join query ($row->id which is the id
        // from the state table
        $this->db->where('state_id',$row->id);
        $r[] = $this->db->get('city')->result();
    }
    return $r;
 }
 else 
 {
     return null;   
 }
```

So now you should have an array of results and can iterate with the foreach in your view.

Comment: it shows the cities now. but another problem is appearing that is only the cities that is under the last state is showing. for example i have 3 states. The cities which is under state 3 is showing, not others.

Comment: Oh, missed that. Updated my answer to give you an array of results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you need a second query inside a loop. Can't you just do:

```
if ($sql->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $sql->result();
}
```

?